# ios and sqlite: 4 values for 5 columns

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Notebook1.sqlite"]];
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);

    if ([fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:databasePath]==NO) 
    {
        const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];    
        NSLog(@"hohoho, %s",dbpath);
        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &noteDB)==SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            char *errMsg;
            const char *sql_str = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Notebook1 (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Whattime Text, Address TEXT, What TEXT, Who TEXT, NOTE TEXT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(noteDB, sql_str, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)!=SQLITE_OK) 
            {
                NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
            }


            sqlite3_close(noteDB);
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
        }
    }
    self.title = @"Add new";
}

-(IBAction)addNote:(id)sender
{
    char *errMsg;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &noteDB)==SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSLog(@"we are here");
        NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Notebook1(Whattime, Address, What, Who, Note) VALUES(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\"\"%@\",\"%@\")", self.whenField.text, self.whenField.text, self.whenField.text,self.whenField.text, self.whenField.text];
        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_exec(noteDB, insert_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)==SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            self.whenField.text = @"";
            self.whereField.text = @"";
            self.whatField.text = @"";
            self.whoField.text = @"";
            self.noteView.text = @"";

            [self doAlert:@"add ok"];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"error： %s",errMsg);
            sqlite3_free(errMsg);
        }

        sqlite3_close(noteDB);
    }
}
```

In "viewDidLoad" the program create a sqlite table that has 6 attributes: ID, Whattime, Address, What, who, Note.
In "addNote", I'm trying to insert some data into the database.
But it failed to do so and the log says: 
2013-10-12 05:10:49.328 Notebook[4266:a0b] error： 4 values for 5 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sqlite table has 6 attributes: ID, Whattime, Address, What, who, Note. and you are inserting only 5 values i.e you are not inserting the value of ID for that you have to insert the value of ID too. If you want your ID to be auto increment than try this :

```
-(IBAction)addNote:(id)sender
{
    NSString *dbFilePath =[DBclass getDBPath];

    sqlite3_stmt *addStmt = nil;
    if(sqlite3_open([dbFilePath UTF8String], &database)==SQLITE_OK)
    {

        const char *sql ="INSERT INTO Notebook1(ID,Whattime, Address, What, Who, Note) Values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating detail view statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

        const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_bind_int (addStmt, 1,   ID);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2,  [self.whenField.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 3,  [self.whenField.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 4,  [self.whenField.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 5,  [self.whenField.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 6,  [self.whenField.text UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        else
            //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
            ID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);


        sqlite3_close(database);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma in here `\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\"\"%@\",\"%@\"` in this line:

```
  NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Notebook1(Whattime, Address, What, Who, Note) VALUES(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\"\"%@\",\"%@\")", self.whenField.text, self.whenField.text, self.whenField.text,self.whenField.text, self.whenField.text];
```

It should be like this:

```
   NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO Notebook1(Whattime, Address, What, Who, Note) VALUES(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")", self.whenField.text, self.whenField.text, self.whenField.text,self.whenField.text, self.whenField.text];
```

Comment: It's a bad idea (and error prone) to use string formats to build the query. It's much better to use `sqlite3_bind_xxx` as shown in the answer by iMove.